# do_shortcode isn't parsing shortcode inside

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I'm trying to use `do_shortcode` in a shortcode function. The problem is that when I use `[terms_and_conditions]` on my page it doesn't parse the `do_shortcode` and I see `[MM_Form_Field type='custom' id='1' isRequired='true' class='']`. It isn't being executed.

This is what my function looks like:

```
function terms_and_conditions( $atts ) {
    // Variables
    $terms = get_field('terms_content', 'options');
    $checkbox = get_field('terms_checkbox_msg', 'options');
    // $smarttag = get_field('terms_smarttag', 'options');
    $smarttag = do_shortcode(get_field('terms_smarttag', 'options'));

    var_dump($smarttag);

    $html_out = '';

    $html_out .= '<section id="terms">';

        $html_out .= '<div class="terms-content-wrapper">';
            $html_out .= $terms;
        $html_out .= '</div>'; // end terms-content-wrapper

        $html_out .= '<div class="terms-checkbox-wrapper">';
            $html_out .= '<div class="terms-checkbox">';
                $html_out .= do_shortcode($smarttag);
                $html_out .= '<p>' . $checkbox . '</p>';
            $html_out .= '</div>'; // end terms-checkbox
        $html_out .= '</div>'; // end terms-content-wrapper

    $html_out .= '</section>'; // end tip-wrapper

    return $html_out;
}
add_shortcode( 'terms_and_conditions', 'terms_and_conditions');
```

Comment: What does `get_field('terms_smarttag', 'options')` return exactly? Also, are you doing some strange shortcode magic or is running do_shortcode on the return value of do_shortcode a mistake?

Comment: @janh someone told me that in this instance I need to run `do_shortcode` twice. I thought it was incorrect too, and I orignally had it as `$html_out .= $smarttag;`. The `get_field` returns [MM_Form_Field type='custom' id='1' isRequired='true' class=''].

Comment: What's the content of `get_field('terms_smarttag', 'options')`. I don't think you need to run do-shortcode twice. might want to consider nesting them: `[shortcode_a][shortcode_b][/shortcode_a]`

Comment: @admcfajn I was hoping for a solution that was in the form of a shortcode function like this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ob_start` can clean up your shortcodes drastically. But you may prefer to avoid them. This should work...

```
<?php
function terms_and_conditions( $atts ) {
    // Variables
    $terms = get_field('terms_content', 'options');
    $checkbox = get_field('terms_checkbox_msg', 'options');
    $smarttag = get_field('terms_smarttag', 'options');

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <section id="terms">
        <div class="terms-content-wrapper">
        <?php
        if($terms){
            echo $terms; // <- is terms an array or a string?
        }
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="terms-checkbox-wrapper">
            <div class="terms-checkbox">
                <?php 
                echo do_shortcode($smarttag); 
                if(!empty($checkbox)){
                    echo '<p>' . $checkbox . '</p>'; // <- is checkbox an array or a string?
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'terms_and_conditions', 'terms_and_conditions');
```

Another thing you may want to try is changing the quotes you use in your shortcode:

eg, use this:

```
[MM_Form_Field type="custom" id="1" isRequired="true" class=""]
```

instead of this:

```
[MM_Form_Field type='custom' id='1' isRequired='true' class='']
```